# Excel userforms

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba, microsoft-excel-2010

I have developed a macro that does a whole bunch of things for me based on a few things.
(Importing files).

The file names are dated `dd_mm_yyyy` and right now I enter them into a sheet where the macro can retrieve the information. Not really wanting this I designed a userform where the user can enter the "dd", "mm", "yyyy" and how many consecutive days of files there are.

For example:

```
28_06_2011.txt

29_06_2011.txt
```

there would be one consecutive day.

I want to be able to retrieve the information entered in the userform (day, month, year, and consecutive days) to use in the macro and have been unsuccessful because I don't know how to access that information. Is it similar to referring to a range in a worksheet?

[image: The userform I designed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Something like:

```
Me.Textbox1.Value
```

Every control has a name, which you can get (and set) by right-clicking on the textbox in design mode and choosing properties.

'Me' refers to the Form itself.

Comment: I realize I can use it to program the Userform itself but can I use the "Me" Object(?) inside the macro? 

When i tried to use the user-form to set variables for the macro it didn't work.

Comment: You can also pass parameters or use a class or a global.  Global variables would be the easiest, but also the easiest to mess up, but I've used a few in VBA when I needed them.

Comment: It worked, I guess I just didn't understand the idea that the "textbox1" was an object and held a value. Like the comparison worksheet to a cell or range as a userform is to a field or control